# Importing Excel of multiple sheets into QGIS

Tags: qgis, excel

I have an excel document of multiple separate sheets.

I can import them one at a time by saving the individual sheets as CSV’s but is there away to bring the entire document into QGIS?

The information is point geometries.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [plugin: Spreadsheet Layers](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SpreadsheetLayers/) that can load excel layers into QGIS. I did not test the plugin and never used it, but you can give it a try to see if it can solve your problem.

There are some limitation in the plugin, you can check everything from plugin page: [QGIS-SpreadSheetLayers](https://github.com/camptocamp/QGIS-SpreadSheetLayers)

Answer (score 2):

After qgis3.8,you can direct access to sheets from XLSX/ODS files from browser,see the details:

[Changelog for QGIS 3.8](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog38/index.html#feature-direct-access-to-sheets-from-xlsx-ods-files)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue around data arrangement. Without rearranging the data, in short the answer is no.